# most common idtreatment from php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array thats returned form a query showing me all bookings in a certain time period.  I'm trying to find the most common treatment in this array.  The treatment is in the array as idtreatment.  How would I even begin to search through an array to find the most common value of idtreatment?  I have tried using

```
          $return = array();
        foreach ($treatment as $a) 
        {
           foreach ($treatment as $b) 
           {
               if ($a === $b) continue;
               $return = array_merge($return, array_intersect($a, $b));
           }
        }
```

where $treatment is the array below but  it just seems to include all the other common values rather than just looking at idtreatment and only taking that into account

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 30255
        [idtreatment] => 65
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 1
        [iduser] => 632
        [idstylist] => 65
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 1
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 09:00:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2017-01-02 18:41:43
        [bookingETime] => 09:30:00
        [bookingToken] => GAsW3k8ASEQo7iS1SScIrt7lB9l31ZHHAaDCvKdnp4LvlDwewIXXb5i
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 20
        [bookingRebooked] => 0
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 20
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Shellac Fingers 

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 28849
        [idtreatment] => 168
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 214
        [idstylist] => 73
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 1704
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 09:00:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-11-16 18:44:55
        [bookingETime] => 09:45:00
        [bookingToken] => cCdXCwqAR7xa75CBwr3LvSxCWjC2YKHamU8YrxziE7tLa6mHwos3h1F
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 20
        [bookingRebooked] => 1
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 20
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Shellac Fingers & Remove

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 30253
        [idtreatment] => 65
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 334
        [idstylist] => 65
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 70
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 09:30:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-12-31 14:37:14
        [bookingETime] => 10:00:00
        [bookingToken] => 4if86rm0vsxbqIf2V20Xu4XHCKJeZ3U3k0aqBwz7Z8iqPysKzBI5FGM
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 20
        [bookingRebooked] => 0
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 20
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Shellac Fingers 

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 29512
        [idtreatment] => 63
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 330
        [idstylist] => 73
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 65
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 09:45:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-12-07 17:36:04
        [bookingETime] => 10:00:00
        [bookingToken] => QMHxMb5PkACXcUWxpDBbIoV8zy6up9ufUcMHoRwIr9FE4CcsfNEXcz6
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 10
        [bookingRebooked] => 1
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 10
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Eyebrow Thread 

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 29513
        [idtreatment] => 436
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 330
        [idstylist] => 73
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 65
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 10:00:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-12-07 17:36:21
        [bookingETime] => 10:15:00
        [bookingToken] => JkFvtRL2avOptokPQMTKnEh2129CzTcidSNGJyIU5wjyVEnMrgwPUOR
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 0
        [bookingRebooked] => 1
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 0
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Face Mapping - 15 Mins

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 29511
        [idtreatment] => 65
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 330
        [idstylist] => 73
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 65
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 10:15:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-12-07 17:35:35
        [bookingETime] => 10:45:00
        [bookingToken] => qVLGE2zwPpPXexiZCs8WVQuOlHQRpQGQMswru7XkwMhKkAJX4QTZHoO
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 20
        [bookingRebooked] => 30380
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 20
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Shellac Fingers 

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [idbooking] => 28867
        [idtreatment] => 206
        [idtreatmentLocation] => 
        [iduser] => 3474
        [idstylist] => 65
        [idbranch] => 1
        [idStatus] => 1
        [idsystem] => 1
        [bookingCreatedBy] => 65
        [bookingDate] => 2017-01-05
        [bookingSTime] => 10:30:00
        [bookingCreated] => 2016-11-17 10:28:49
        [bookingETime] => 10:45:00
        [bookingToken] => ZVapypjdIrENXPyvi9fTuKvEWKgCE6gE2q4zQmNyOrlLgUgy4wsxhXc
        [bookingComplete] => 1
        [bookingPrice] => 17
        [bookingRebooked] => 1
        [bookingPatchTest] => 0
        [bookingPriceAmend] => 0
        [bookingTreatPrice] => 17
        [bookingLink] => 0
        [isLunch] => 0
        [treatmentName] => Eyebrow Thread 

    )
)
```

Comment: your code is working fine.http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0453f75ba3e1668c986ac7725e39bdf50f74eb8

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Suchit yes but it seems to be taking into account all the other values in the array as well which is making the result set incorrect.

Comment: @RossWilson no error anymore I had the code written wrong I will edit the question a little.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson PHP 5.3 :)

Comment: @RossWilson I have made my array much more manageable now but I'm still struggling.  The array now looks like this.       Array
(
    [0] => 65
    [1] => 168
    [2] => 65
    [3] => 63
    [4] => 436
    [5] => 65
    [6] => 206
    [7] => 47
    [8] => 93
    [9] => 45
    [10] => 152
    [11] => 99
    [12] => 206
    [13] => 97
    [14] => 74
    [15] => 206
    [16] => 74
    [17] => 97
    [18] => 218
   
)

Comment: @RossWilson  I will edit the question again

Comment: You question now doesn't make sense to anyone else who comes along. If you go back to how it was I can give you an answer.

Comment: @RossWilson ok 1 moment

Comment: @RossWilson I have put it back to the way I started :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off your `$treatment` array if you want to the most common occurrence  of `idtreatment` you could do something like:

```
$idTreatments = [];

foreach ($treatment as $value) {

    $id = $value['idtreatment'];

    if (!isset($idTreatments[$id])) {
        $idTreatments[$id] = 0;
    }

    $idTreatments[$id]++;
}

arsort($idTreatments);

$commonTreatment = key($idTreatments);
```

If you're using PHP 5.5+ you could use `array_column` and `array_count_values` instead of the `foreach` loop:

```
$idTreatments = array_count_values(array_column($treatment, 'idtreatment'));
```

Hope this helps!